# How can I read an EPub file in C# on Windows phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, epub

I'm developing an **WP 8.1 application**, and I need to **read an EPub file**.

Unfortunately, all the API found were discontinued, for this reason, I am trying to use generic API for C#, like [this](https://epubreader.codeplex.com/).

```
string file = @"c:\books\example.epub";

        try {
               //Initialize EPub object
            Epub epub = new Epub(file);
        }
```

There is an error in object initialization...

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Apparently, it does not find the file.

In describing the API above, warns may need to use the following [API](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/), but I don't know how and why.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you try to access to "c:" on Windows Phone.

Try to read this post for how to read a file.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34583303/how-to-read-a-text-file-in-windows-universal-app