# how to read a text file in windows universal app

Tags: c#, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I am trying to read a text file named thedata.txt that has a list of words that I want to use in a hangman game.  I have tried different ways, but I can't figure out where the file gets placed, if at all when the app runs.  I added the file to my project, and I have tried setting the build properties to content, and then embedded resource, but can't find the file.  I have made a Windows 10 universal app project.  The code I tried looks like this:

```
  Stream stream = this.GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("thedata.txt");
            using (StreamReader inputStream = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                while (inputStream.Peek() >= 0)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("the line is ", inputStream.ReadLine());
                }
            }
```

I get exceptions.
I also tried to list the files in another directory:

```
 string path = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path;
            Debug.WriteLine("The path is " + path);
            IReadOnlyCollection<StorageFile> files = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFilesAsync();
            foreach (StorageFile file2 in files)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Name 2 is " + file2.Name + ", " + file2.DateCreated);
            }
```

I don't see the file there either...I want to avoid hard coding the list of names in my program.  I'm not sure what the path that the file is placed.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

the code is very simple, you just have to use a valid scheme URI (ms-appx in your case) and transform your WinRT InputStream as a classic .NET stream :

```
var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///thedata.txt"));
using (var inputStream = await file.OpenReadAsync())
using (var classicStream = inputStream.AsStreamForRead())
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(classicStream))
{
    while (streamReader.Peek() >= 0)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("the line is {0}", streamReader.ReadLine()));
    }
}
```

For the properties of the embedded file, "Build Action" must be set to "Content" and "Copy to Ouput Directory" should be set to "Do not Copy".

Comment: The above code provided by t.ouvre answered my question.  I have verified that it works on my computer and my emulator.  Thank you for answering my question.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

You can't use classic .NET IO methods in Windows Runtime apps, the proper way to read a text file in UWP is:

```
var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("data.txt");
var lines = await FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(file);
```

Also, you don't need a physical path of a folder - from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefolder.path.aspx) :

> Don't rely on this property to access a folder, because a file system
>   path is not available for some folders. For example, in the following
>   cases, the folder may not have a file system path, or the file system
>   path may not be available. •The folder represents a container for a
>   group of files (for example, the return value from some overloads of
>   the GetFoldersAsync method) instead of an actual folder in the file
>   system. •The folder is backed by a URI. •The folder was picked by
>   using a file picker.

Answer (score 4):

Please refer [File access permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt188700.aspx) for more details.
And [Create, write, and read a file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/mt185401) provides examples related with File IO for UWP apps on Windows 10.

You can retrieve a file directly from your app's local folder by using an app URI, like this:

```
using Windows.Storage;

StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync("ms-appdata:///local/file.txt");
```