# C# cannot convert from string to System.IO.Stream

Tags: c#, windows, file, io, stream

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("saveData.txt");
```

I've written this and I get the error "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IO.Stream'.
I've used this exact same code in a console application and it worked fine, but putting this into a Windows Universal Application gives this error.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried this?

```
MemoryStream memoryStream= new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("saveData.txt"));
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Windows Universal Application reading file functionality is different:

```
var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("data.txt");
var lines = await FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(file);
```

Source : [how to read a text file in windows universal app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34583303/how-to-read-a-text-file-in-windows-universal-app)