# How to read a text file in a folder that I included in the uwp desktop project?

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a folder with text files needed to launch the uwp desktop application I'm working on. I include this folder in the project. The question is how to read the existing text files in the folder? I tried the code below, but it didn't work. Throws a bad path exception.

```
string strPath = "ms-appx:///MyData/structure.txt";
string strStructure = File.ReadAllText(strPath);
```

Comment: perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34583620/4935162)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the problem. I placed the file in the root folder of the project and used the following code.

```
StorageFolder installedLocation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
StorageFile file = await installedLocation.GetFileAsync("structure.lst");
IList<string> data = await FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(file);
```